# Sort folders by custom value in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sorting, files-folders

I am currently cataloguing a large amount of family photos and I have gotten to a point where I would need to sort a lot of folders by a custom value.

From what I gathered on the internet, Windows doesn't seem to have straightforward way to do that - however.

The most common workaround being suggested seems to be following:

1. create a desktop.ini file within the folder;
2. edit its ***InfoTip*** field to the value that you desire.

Doing that allows you to sort the folders by this custom value in the Details view (***Infotip*** appears as ***Comments*** in Explorer), as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2X4E.png).

While not perfect (you have to open the folder and then the file to do that), this method would be good enough ...if it actually worked.

In practice, there are two issues that prevent me from using it:

1. The refresh time is incredibly slow - even refreshing the folder, sometimes it takes **minutes** for the custom value to appear and\or be updated;
2. Some folders won't display this custom field regardless of how many times you refresh the container. I have tried changing the value of the Infotip field, copying the entire desktop.ini file from a working folder, etc. - to no avail.

---

My question is thus the following: *are there better ways of sorting folders by a custom value in Windows?*

Comment: Why fight the system? Just use 001 - School; 002 - Holidays, etc

Comment: For reasons too long to explain here, I cannot change the name - I need a secondary sorting system in addition to it.

Comment: What will you be doing with the sorted list? How are the custom values associated to the folders - do you have a list, or what?

Comment: @erm - You will have to use a third-party shell replacement that supports your ordering requirements since File Explorer does not support it

Comment: I'm afraid so :( Do you know any I could try?